# Forcing a common z-scale in a surface groupplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I've come across some similar questions, but not this exact one.  And nothing I've tried has been able to achieve precisely what I'm looking for.

I have a groupplot that contains two overhead views of surface plots.  The code (not an MWE) that produces them is

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{extikzpicture}[runs=2]{fig6}
        \begin{groupplot}[
                group style={group size=2 by 1,
                             group name = fig6_plots,
                             xlabels at=edge bottom,
                             ylabels at=edge left                                                                                     
                            },
                            xlabel = {\footnotesize $\alpha_{++}$},
                            ylabel = {\footnotesize Departure Rate},
                            view={0}{90},
                            colorbar horizontal,
                            colormap/blackwhite,
                            y tick label style={
                                /pgf/number format/.cd,
                                fixed,
                                fixed zerofill,
                                precision=2,
                                /tikz/.cd
                            },
                            x tick label style={
                                /pgf/number format/.cd,
                                fixed,
                                fixed zerofill,
                                precision=0,
                                /tikz/.cd
                            }]
                            \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Come and Go}]
                               \addplot3[surf, shader=interp,colormap/blackwhite] file {ComeAndGoSurface.txt};
                            \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize ++Resources}]
                                \addplot3[surf, shader=interp,colormap/blackwhite] file {PPResourcesSurface.txt};
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{extikzpicture}
    \caption{++Resources and Come and Go}
    \label{HeatMap}
\end{figure}
```

The output looks like

[image]

Note the different colorbar scales.  I'd like to be able to force them both to use the same Z-scale so that they'll use the same colorbar.  Then I could just produce one colorbar centered between the two and it would facilitate comparison.  But I can't find any way to do that.

For reference, here is an early figure that shows both surfaces on a single plot.  I felt it didn't render very well in black and white (which is required for the journal I'm submitting to) so I tried switching to the two "heat map" views.

[image]

Comment: I suspect (without seeing the data) that the mean and sd are different in the two data sets.   So before you input the data into `\addplot` you need to *normalize* each data set.  (This is a basic stats issue.)  `Zscore=(x-meanx)/sdx`

Comment: I'm not sure that's what I'm after.  I just edited the original post to include a figure that shows the 3D view of both surfaces.  When they're on the same plot like that they obviously have a common Z-scale.  But I didn't think that plot rendered very well in black and white.  So I tried switching to the overhead "heat map" view.

Comment: Adding `point meta min` and `point meta max` to your axis configurations allows to sync the color maps and color bars. In order to place + align a single color bar, you may want to consider section "4.9.13 Color Bars Outside Of an Axis" of the pgfplots reference manual and, in particular, the key `colorbar to name` combined with `\ref`

Answer (score 3):

Many thanks!  I knew how to build the common color bar, just not how to force the scale to be common.  Solution looks like this

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{extikzpicture}[runs=2]{fig6}
        \begin{groupplot}[point meta min=4,point meta max=15,
                group style={group size=2 by 1,
                            group name = fig6_plots,
                             xlabels at=edge bottom,
                             ylabels at=edge left
                            },
                            xlabel = {\footnotesize $\alpha_{++}$},
                            ylabel = {\footnotesize Departure Rate},
                            view={0}{90},
                            colorbar horizontal,
                            colorbar to name=ContourColorbar,
                            colormap/blackwhite,
                            y tick label style={
                                /pgf/number format/.cd,
                                fixed,
                                fixed zerofill,
                                precision=2,
                                /tikz/.cd
                            },
                            x tick label style={
                                /pgf/number format/.cd,
                                fixed,
                                fixed zerofill,
                                precision=0,
                                /tikz/.cd
                            }]
                \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Come and Go}]
                        \addplot3[surf, shader=interp,colormap/blackwhite] file {ComeAndGoSurface.txt};
                \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize ++Resources}]
                        \addplot3[surf, shader=interp,colormap/blackwhite] file {PPResourcesSurface.txt};
        \end{groupplot}
        \node (fig6_Legend) at ($(fig6_plots c1r1.center)!0.5!(fig6_plots c2r1.center)-(0,4.5cm)$){\ref{ContourColorbar}};
    \end{extikzpicture}
    \caption{++Resources and Come and Go}
    \label{HeatMap}
\end{figure}
```

Output looks like
[image]