# Groupplot with piecewise constant colorbar

Tags: tikz-pgf, groupplots

I'm currently in the progress of attempting to combine my custom colorbar with a 2x1 groupplot such that it is shared. 
I've come quite far with the help of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126177/common-colorbar-for-groupplot) topic, but arrived at an impasse.

The problem is that for some reason (I've isolated it to the introduction of 
the `colorbar sampled` option) a second color bar is introduced for second plot, whereas I never request it. 
To clarify, what I'm trying to achieve is the single colorbar spanning both plot, i.e. the top one that is displaying in the figure  below.

I've put together a minimal working example, that works with the custom colorbar, ensures the correct colorbar height and illustrates the problem and put it below this output figure which illustrates the problem:

[image: result of minimal example]

Is anyone able to direct me towards a solution/fix to the problem? Although the minimal example might not indicate it, I do need the `piecewise constant` colorbar.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\newlength\fheight
\newlength\fwidth

\begin{document}
\scriptsize
\centering
\setlength\fheight{4cm} 
\setlength\fwidth{5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{groupplot}[%
group style={group size=1 by 2,
xlabels at = edge bottom},
colormap={mymap}{[1pt]
rgb=(0.267004,0.00487433,0.329415);
rgb=(0.28315,0.113698,0.434361);
rgb=(0.271534,0.2104,0.505038);
rgb=(0.239637,0.300176,0.540669);
rgb=(0.202221,0.381534,0.554096);
rgb=(0.169529,0.456548,0.558034);
rgb=(0.140966,0.528998,0.555761);
rgb=(0.119984,0.601236,0.54219);
rgb=(0.146361,0.672773,0.509112);
rgb=(0.24974,0.740687,0.44999);
rgb=(0.405343,0.8007,0.361742);
rgb=(0.593466,0.848243,0.244848);
rgb=(0.797749,0.881204,0.118069);
rgb=(0.993248,0.906157,0.143936)},
colorbar sampled,
colormap access=piecewise constant,
colorbar style={
samples=14,
},
group/xlabels at = edge bottom,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
]

\nextgroupplot[
width=0.838\fwidth,
height=\fheight,
scale only axis,
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
colorbar,
every colorbar/.append style={height=
    2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/parent axis height}+
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/group/vertical sep}}]
]

\addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};

\nextgroupplot[
width=0.838\fwidth,
height=\fheight,
scale only axis,
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
]

\addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Or did I simply encounter a flaw in `pgfplots`? Is the problem at least reproducible from the MWE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not consider this a fix to the problem, but I did find a workaround by following suggestions in this [topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245903/forcing-a-common-z-scale-in-a-surface-groupplot/246119); to use the

> Color Bars Outside Of an Axis

option from the [pgf manual](http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf). I am posting this because it does provide the desired result hoping it provides useful for someone else.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\newlength\fheight
\newlength\fwidth

\begin{document}
\scriptsize
\centering
\setlength\fheight{4cm} 
\setlength\fwidth{5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{groupplot}[%
    group style={group size=1 by 2,
    group name=scatter_combined,
    xlabels at = edge bottom},
    colormap={mymap}{[1pt]
    rgb=(0.267004,0.00487433,0.329415);
    rgb=(0.28315,0.113698,0.434361);
    rgb=(0.271534,0.2104,0.505038);
    rgb=(0.239637,0.300176,0.540669);
    rgb=(0.202221,0.381534,0.554096);
    rgb=(0.169529,0.456548,0.558034);
    rgb=(0.140966,0.528998,0.555761);
    rgb=(0.119984,0.601236,0.54219);
    rgb=(0.146361,0.672773,0.509112);
    rgb=(0.24974,0.740687,0.44999);
    rgb=(0.405343,0.8007,0.361742);
    rgb=(0.593466,0.848243,0.244848);
    rgb=(0.797749,0.881204,0.118069);
    rgb=(0.993248,0.906157,0.143936)},
    colorbar sampled,
    colormap access=piecewise constant,
    colorbar style={
    samples=14,
    },
    colorbar to name=sharedcolorbar,
    group/xlabels at = edge bottom,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    every colorbar/.append style={height=
        2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/parent axis height}+
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/group/vertical sep}},
    ]

    \nextgroupplot[
    width=0.838\fwidth,
    height=\fheight,
    scale only axis,
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids,
    ]

    \addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};

    \nextgroupplot[
    width=0.838\fwidth,
    height=\fheight,
    scale only axis,
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids,
    ]

  \addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};

  \end{groupplot}
  \node (fig6_Legend) at ($(scatter_combined c1r1.center)!0.5!(scatter_combined c1r2.center)+(0.6\fwidth,0)$){\ref{sharedcolorbar}};


\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

In a moment of inspiration I removed the `every` from the `every colorbar` key and it worked (I guess). Is this what you want?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\newlength\fheight
\newlength\fwidth

\begin{document}
\scriptsize
\centering
\setlength\fheight{4cm} 
\setlength\fwidth{5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{groupplot}[%
group style={group size=1 by 2,
xlabels at = edge bottom},
colormap={mymap}{[1pt]
rgb=(0.267004,0.00487433,0.329415);
rgb=(0.28315,0.113698,0.434361);
rgb=(0.271534,0.2104,0.505038);
rgb=(0.239637,0.300176,0.540669);
rgb=(0.202221,0.381534,0.554096);
rgb=(0.169529,0.456548,0.558034);
rgb=(0.140966,0.528998,0.555761);
rgb=(0.119984,0.601236,0.54219);
rgb=(0.146361,0.672773,0.509112);
rgb=(0.24974,0.740687,0.44999);
rgb=(0.405343,0.8007,0.361742);
rgb=(0.593466,0.848243,0.244848);
rgb=(0.797749,0.881204,0.118069);
rgb=(0.993248,0.906157,0.143936)},
colorbar sampled,
colormap access=piecewise constant,
colorbar style={
samples=14,
},
group/xlabels at = edge bottom,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
]

\nextgroupplot[
width=0.838\fwidth,
height=\fheight,
scale only axis,
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
colorbar,
% every colorbar/.append style={height=% <------ REMOVED every FROM HERE
colorbar/.append style={height=
    2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/parent axis height}+
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/group/vertical sep}}]
]

\addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};

\nextgroupplot[
width=0.838\fwidth,
height=\fheight,
scale only axis,
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
]

\addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's one moment of brilliance, and such a simple solution. What I was trying to achieve, however, is the single colorbar being shared by both plots, so one large bar like to top one in my figure.

Comment: @SteynW. Oh, sorry, I misunderstood the question. I'll leave the answer here for further reference. But in a few days you can accept yours.

Comment: No problem, thanks for thinking along! Can say you did trigger my inspiration to think outside the box.